# Can a custom model binder be made async?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a custom model binder that needs to access the database. I can do this synchronously but I would like to do it asynchronously.

```
public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var json = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; // nothing to see here
    Truck truck = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Truck>(json);
    truck.Availability = await _truckRepo.GetAvailability(truck.Id); // <-- problem. BindModel is a synchronous method
}
```

Of course there are other ways to hydrate this object. I could just set it on the first line in the controller. But I will always need to get `Availability` so it would be nice if it were already hydrated when it arrived at the controller. I could force this to run synchronously by doing `truck.Availability = _truckRepo.GetAvailability(truck.Id).Result` but then it would be ...synchronous. Is there a way to do this and have it still be asynchronous? What if I wrap it all in a task, do the awaits inside the task, and then force the task to be synchronous? Like this:

```
var success = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var json = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Truck truck = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Truck>(json);
    truck.Availability = await _truckRepo.GetAvailability(truck.Id);
    return true;
}).Result;
```

Assuming the database call takes a long time (idk say three seconds) am I getting any benefit from doing it that way?

Comment: You would still have a dedicated thread waiting on the result and the overhead of the async/await.

Comment: A better option also logically would be to add an `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` type to enrich the instance if this was common code (reused code). That does allow for async and you could add a filter type named GetAvailabilityAttribute

Comment: You are making the model binding mechanism do things it was never intended for. It was invented (as far as I know) with relatively simple things in mind, like string-to-datetime conversions, not for data access on the fly. ModelBinding can do syntactic validation and set `ModelState.IsValid` to `false` if input syntax is wrong. Making it actually retrieve data is taking things way too far IMO.